# Attempting to use docker.build() in aj Jenkins pipeline while also defining a specific docker file for use

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

I am attempting to use Jenkins to create a docker instance with a docker.build() command. The issue is that I have more than one docker file (all of which have unique names) which will be used on different scenarios.  Is there a way to use the docker.build command in Jenkins while also specifying which file to use?

```
api = docker.build("api:Dockerfile-api")
```

I am attempting to emulate functionality for the command

```
docker build -t <app-name>-api -f Dockerfile-api .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

talking about docker-pipeline-plugin, the second argument the `docker.build()` function takes can be `docker.build("svc", "-f docker/db/Dockerfile .")`